# Area of cyclic pentagon

Tags: geometry

Can anyone give an **explicit formula** for the area of a cyclic pentagon in terms of its sides? Just like Herons formula, and Brahmaguptas formula,  I hope there exists a similar formula for cyclic pentagons.

A proof would be especially appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Not with *just* sides. Because given 5 sides, $a,b,c,d,e$ there exist a lot of pentagons with different areas and those 5 sides. In a triangle, on the other hand, 3 sides "fixes" the triangle.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Its also cyclic.

Comment: @mathlearner refresh my memory. cyclic means in a circle? i missed that.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Yes. And you can always Google that.

Comment: and I should have. apologies. I didn't the first time round, since it didn't catch my eye.

Comment: @mathlearner I saw another equation around here regarding some equation on pentagons. Lemme check

Comment: @mathlearner will [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705354/can-this-be-converted-into-a-polynomial-equation-for-x) do?

Comment: @Sabyasachi That does not give me an explicit formula!

Comment: I *think*, I really can't comprehend that, that $x$ is the area there? or T?

Comment: @Sabyasachi If you see carefully $x$ is a diagonal, and $T$ is the area [sum of a quad + sun of a tri = sum of the pent]. But if that is the area formula, it includes one diagonal, bummer.

Comment: @mathlearner which diagonal though?